# Texture isn't showing up

Tags: texturing

I've spend all my yesterday painting a model, but today when I load it up the texture is no longer fully showing - instead, I only see the base color I picked when creating the texture. In the "Active Tool" I can still see the mini-icon of the the full texture, so I stil quite hope the work is not lost.
Thanks for any help, and sorry for my poor English
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you did not save the image texture **externally** first, you will not have access to the image when you reload the file. I only know this because I have done this many times myself!

In order to maintain the file, save it from the image editor:`Image > Save As`.
Then choose a location on your drive to save the image.
When you paint on it again, you will be able to see it when you reload the file, and remember to go to `Image > Save` every so often so you don't lose any work!